# top bar is clipped, hiding site switcher, on non-responsive pages with new design

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, top-bar, responsive-design

The new top bar adjusts to the window size instead of clipping important stuff off to the right in smaller viewports.  However, on sites with the new responsive design, individual *pages* that aren't yet responsive now clip the top bar.  This is a screen shot from my Meta.SE profile in Firefox 60.0.1 on Windows 7 in a window that's currently 1036px wide:

[image: MSE, clipped top bar]

Here's another site for comparison:

[image: Mi Yodeya, not clipped]

The "ask question" page is one of the ones that's not responsive, by the way, so I had to side-scroll to get to the site switchers to get the second screen shot.

I know that eventually everything will be responsive, but that's going to take a while.  In the meantime the top bar has regressed.  Can we fix that?

A comment asked about zoom.  I reproduced it at 100% zoom and then zoomed out a few more notches for good measure.  Zoom does not affect the layout of the top-bar icons:

[image: zoomed out super-far]

Comment: It looks like you're zoomed to about 115-120%.  Are you able to reproduce the bug at 100% zoom?  Also, what browser are you using?  I've been able to reproduce it when zoomed in on Safari, but other browsers seem to handle it okay.

Comment: @BrianNickel it actually seems to be 100% zoom (didn't see any changes on a ctrl-0).  The problem persists as I change zoom, including really far out.  I updated with a new screen shot and to add the browser (Firefox 60.0.1, Windows).

Comment: That's weird.  I have the same Firefox on Windows 10 and have a completely different zooming behavior. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAInQ.png  The reason I believe your page is zoomed is that your headers are bigger than I get on any of my browser. https://i.stack.imgur.com/o36rW.png Similarly, the screenshot you just added also has uneven lines on the hamburger menu, consistent with pixel snapped zooming.  Since you have a muted background color, I'm guessing you have custom CSS, assistive technology, or an add-on in effect on the page.  That could be causing this.

Comment: @BrianNickel ah, looks like a userscript.  Investigating.  (I'm not using any "modify the topbar" scripts, but I still should have checked.) Update: damn, it's SOUP.  That hurts.

Comment: I added a SOUP issue here: https://github.com/vyznev/soup/issues/41

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm marking this a declined this since the issue is caused by the SOUP userscript.  You can follow Monica's issue here: https://github.com/vyznev/soup/issues/41

Comment: Thanks for investigating, and sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: The SOUP issue has now been fixed.